# How to send an equivalent of a curl command from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, json, curl

I have been looking at this SO post: 
[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

and I have a slightly different situation.  Have this curl command which works:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d 'some json' http://127.0.0.1:9010/api/kpi
```

but now I need to put this sort of a thing into a JavaScript file and it obviously breaks.

Could someone please help me create this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript doesn't have curl, the closest equivalent would be AJAX.  But you cannot make a post (ajax) request in javascript to a domain other than the current page's domain, as this is considered cross-site scripting.

Comment: note: one "workaround" is to make an ajax request to the same domain your page the page is on, and perform the curl server-side and return the results back to javascript in the ajax response